# Mobile hybrid app testing using Codedui

Tags: testing, mobile, ionic-framework, coded-ui-tests, hybrid

I was working on a ionic mobile hybrid app and looking for automation testing tools. I found Codedui a solution for testing windows/web application and I was wondering if this can be used for testing ionic apps as well. I will appreciate if someone who has done similar task can share his views. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never hear about Codedui before, but I suggest to use [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/) to test automatically your App. Protractor runs tests against your application running in a real browser, interacting with it as a user would.

Comment: Yes I know about Protractor but Codedui is a requirement so I am trying to explore.